# VSTS Build Task Input Types

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I googled last few days to get the list of input types supported by VSTS Task plugin, but don't get anything appropriate.

Is this possible to create Grid in task plugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At present, there is no way to create a `Grid` on the task input page. For a complete list of the supported types, take a look at the [Reference for creating custom build tasks within extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/build-task-schema) for details. This is schema definition for what your custom task JSON needs to conform to. If you look under `inputs/items/properties/type` you will see these supported types:

- boolean
- connectedService:ServiceType
- connectedService:AzureRM
- connectedService:Azure
- connectedService:Azure:Certificate,UsernamePassword
- connectedService:Chef
- connectedService:ssh
- connectedService:Generic
- connectedService:Jenkins
- connectedService:servicefabric
- filePath
- multiLine
- pickList
- radio
- string

Comment: I don't see there any input types

Comment: This post is outdated with the changes and improvements Microsoft has done to the Pipelines. I'd suggest asking a new question to better understand your use case.

Comment: If i just want to see the existing types, where can I see them today?

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom editor experiences using a KnockoutJS-based HTML page (via the vss-web-extension-sdk) and registering it as a `ms.vss-distributed-task.task-input-editor` contribution in your extension's `vss-extension.json`.

The [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples) repository includes an example of this in [release-manageent/editor-extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/release-management/editor-extension)

Comment: Maybe you'll know this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834090/azure-pipeline-custom-task-string-input-to-match-regex

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can create custom endpoint and use in task: `connectedService:[endpoint name]`.

[Service Endpoints in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints)

Comment: No, the endpoint is the connection instead of control for task input box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that the string after ':' is the endpoint name. I spent two hours on investigating why service connections are not listed.

Comment: I did create a cusotm service endpoint, and using it in task.json, although in my case, I do not want to show users the service endpoint etc in the build task, and thus added a visibility rule which makes it hidden. With everything else as it is, the task is failing. Is there any way I can make the connectedService field in task.json hidden and use a fixed value(which I know) for the same subsequently to fetch client id and password associated with it?