# How do you add a checkbox input to an Azure DevOps Task Group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-task-groups

In Azure DevOps, I have created a Task Group that runs Postman tests using the `newman` CLI. As inputs, users can pass in the paths to the Postman collection and environment files.

As the `newman` CLI is a requirement, the first task in the Task Group is to install it. However, in scenarios where several collections are run, there is no need to keep installing the CLI over and over, so I would like to offer a checkbox and then conditionally run the install task depending on the value of that checkbox.

As the UI for Task Groups is pretty lacking in useful options, I started exploring the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). I'm able to add additional inputs, but setting the obvious `type` option to `checkbox` yields only an additional text (`string`) input.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1

{
    ...
    "inputs": [
        {
            "aliases": [],
            "options": {},
            "properties": {},
            "name": "Rbt.Cli.Install",
            "label": "Install 'newman' CLI?",
            "defaultValue": true,
            "required": false,
            "type": "checkbox",
            "helpMarkDown": "Choose whether or not to install the 'newman' CLI. You only need to install it if it hasn't already been installed by a previos task running on this job.",
            "groupName": ""
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

Looking more closely at the documentation, there is a definition for inputs - `TaskInputDefinition`. However, it looks as though whoever was tasked with writing [that documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#taskinputdefinition) left early one day and never got around to it. There are no descriptions at all, making it impossible to know valid values for properties in the definition.

How can I add a checkbox to my Task Group?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168077/vsts-build-task-input-types?

Comment: It does, many thanks. That schema was exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found that Task Groups offer `picklist` as an input type. This has allowed be to present a yes/no option to the user, and based on their answer I am able to conditionally run a task.

I would still prefer to have a checkbox though, should anyone know how to do that.

```
{
    "aliases": [],
    "options": {
        "yes": "Yes - install CLI",
        "no": "No - the CLI has already been installed"
    },
    "properties": {},
    "name": "Postman.Cli.Install",
    "label": "Install 'newman' CLI?",
    "defaultValue": "yes",
    "required": true,
    "type": "picklist",
    "helpMarkDown": "Choose whether or not to install the 'newman' CLI. You only need to install it if it hasn't already been installed by a previos task running on this job.",
    "groupName": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkbox to pipeline task easily by setting the type as `boolean`

```
 {
    "name": "Rbt.Cli.Install",
    "type": "boolean",
    "label": "Install 'newman' CLI?"  
 }
```

And also control the visibility of other controls based on the check box state as following:

```
{
    "name": "someOtherField",
    "type": "string",
    "label": "Some other field",
    "visibleRule": "Rbt.Cli.Install = true"
},
```